# MySQL DB-Structure: 1 Device consists of multiple Components

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

First, im a beginner in MySQL.
I try to make the Database-structure like described above.
I have multiple different Devices all in one Table.
I have multiple different Components all in one Table.
Both of the tables has a PK, DEV_nr and CMP_nr.
Now i want to refer (with a FK) from a Device to all its components which the Device contains. f.ex. Device1 consists of Component4,5 and 6.
I thought that i can store a BLOB in the Devices table and make it a FK which refers to multiple Values of the PK of the Components table.
I hope you understand what i mean.
It doesn't work. (I think its also because i refer from a BLOB to a CHAR or INT)
Is something like this possible? How can i achieve that?
Should i start from beginning and make it another way?
Thanks and BR, Dee

Answer (score 0):

What you are needing is referred to as a "junction table". Junction tables are used to turn N:M relationships (devices and components) into 1:M relationships, which keeps your data normalized and easy to query in the future. The structure for such a table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `dev_comp_junction` (
 `dev_comp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `DEV_nr` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `CMP_nr` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`dev_comp_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_dev_comp_DEV` FOREIGN KEY (`DEV_nr`) REFERENCES `DEVTABLE_HERE` (`DEV_nr`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_dev_comp_CMP` FOREIGN KEY (`CMP_nr`) REFERENCES `CMPTABLE_HERE` (`CMP_nr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Ok i see. I need an extra Table and write down the relationships there. Good solution Thanks! Works great.